# Do something after 7zip extracts

Tags: 7zip

After 7zip extracts a file,

How can I make it run a program? The program is in the extracted file.

Is there a way that I can add code to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a security risk for 7zip users.

Comment: I just want to do this so it is easier for my users

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the 7z SFX modules, which are part of the 7z Extras package.

This allows you to create installers with 7z.
See the 7z download site [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) for more information.

The download contains a readme file, as well as an example config file.